# When I can be sure that I can inherit from c++ class?

Tags: c++

Let's say that I use an external library full of various classes. When I can safely inherit from one of those classes? I know that the base class must have a virtual destructor. Is there something else I should check before using the class as the base class? Can I be sure that it is safe only if the docs state so?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: _"I know that the base class must have a virtual destructor."_ That's not true. You can inherit from a class without virtual destructor. You need a virtual desctructor for polymorphism when you destroy an object through a pointer to the base class.

Comment: And not having a virtual destructor doesn't make it "unsafe", it depends on the handling of the derived type. If it's destroyed by a base pointer that doesn't have a virtual destructor, then it can be bad because the derived pointer won't have its destructor called. If it's destroyed as the derived type, this is fine.

Comment: @Pipetus Nothing funny will be hapenning, no data corruption, no some kind of 
unexpected shadowing. No weird implementation specific behavior. I do not care about ABI compatibility or convenience of use. Does that answer the question?

Comment: You can safely inherit from any class that does not have a `final` specifier.  As important is:  how are you using the derived class?  If you are misusing the relationship between the base class and derived class, then bad things can happen.

Answer (score 8):

If the documentation states that it is safe to derive a type, follow the documentation. If, for some reason, it behaves in a way that goes against the documentation, then this is a problem with the library and is a bug for the authors to fix or offer workarounds for, because they are not committing to the API that they guarantee in the documentation.

---

Any type that is not `final` can be derived "safely"; what matters more is how this type is handled and destroyed. If you inherit from a type that has no `virtual` destructor, this doesn't inherently break anything; it just prevents having the derived type's destructor get called if you destroy that from a handle to the base.

If you only ever destroy the type from a handle to the derived type, (e.g. you either hold it concretely, or never destroy it from a handle to the base), then this has no consequence.

To better explain my point, imagine the following hierarchy:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    // No virtual destructor
    ...
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    ...
private:
    std::string m_something; // some leakable object
};
```

The derivation of `Derived` from `Base` is completely safe to do. What matters is how it gets *destroyed* for whether there will be a problem. For this there are two different cases to consider: Automatic and Dynamic cases.

#### Automatic Objects

Automatic types ("by-value" types) are safe, regardless of whether they have static lifetime or not

```cpp
auto d = Derived{ ... };
static auto sd = Derived{ ... };
```

At the end of their lifetime, the destructor `Derived::~Derived` will be called, since the type is concretely known

#### Dynamic Objects

Dynamic objects don't get destroyed on their own. Their resources need to be cleaned up *eventually*, either automatically with RAII in a smart pointer, by someone calling `delete`, or by someone explicitly calling `~T()` and freeing the memory.

These are *still safe* if they are destroyed by a handle to the derived type, but will not be if they are destroyed by a handle to the base.

```cpp
auto* d1 = new Derived{ ... }; 
auto* d2 = new Derived{ ... };

// Deleting as a pointer to Base; ~Derived won't be called because ~Base is virtual
// This would be a memory leak
delete static_cast<Base*>(d1);  // bad 

// Deleting as a pointer to Derived -- ~Derived will be called, this is fine
delete d2; // good
```

In terms of Smart Pointer types:

**Shared Pointer**

`shared_ptr` types are safe, since they always destroy objects from the concrete type -- even if they get aliased to a base class.

```cpp
void accept_base(std::shared_ptr<Base> b);

auto d = std::make_shared<Derived>(...);

// still safe
accept_base(std::move(d));
```

**Unique Pointer**

`unique_ptr` types are not safe *by default* due to the default deleter deleting based on the `T` type of `unique_ptr`.

For example:

```cpp
auto d = std::make_unique<Derived>(...);

auto b = std::unique_ptr<Base>{std::move(d)};

// b will be destroyed at end of scope by calling ~Base, which is not virtual!
```

---

Even with all of this said: If you're using a library that explicitly states that you are meant to derive some XYZ class, then you should still assume that this is how the class should be used. At that point, if something undesirable occurs, it will be up to the library maintainer to ensure that their code performs as documented, since it's part of their expressly stated API.

Comment: Does it mean that virtual constructor is really the only caveat when it comes to inheriting from external classes? I was looking for some more of these "_safe as long as you destroy it through the pointer to the derived_ " cases.

Comment: Do you mean "virtual destructor"? There are no virtual constructors in C++. Virtual dtors only affect whether the behavior of destroying a handle to the base class will call the dtor of the derived class. Otherwise destroying through a pointer to the derived will always be safe, since it will always know the concrete type definition being destroyed.

Comment: Sorry I meant virtual dtor.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, not a guaranteed memory leak, if the wrong destructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to call methods from a Base class reference or pointer, you should also check if they are declared virtual.

Apart from that I would look into the documentation of the class and whether it is declared `final`

You actually do not need a virtual destructor for it to be safe to inherit from a class. You only need a virtual destructor, if you want to use (and thereby destroy) the class from a pointer to its base class.

It all depends on how you intend to use the derived class.

For instance, if you just want to make a class that inherits from the given class, but you do not intend to use it in a base class pointer or reference.

```
Base baseObj;
Derived derivedObject; // This does not create any problems
```

If you want to use it from a pointer or reference (this also applies to smart pointers of course) to the base class like this:

```
Base* basePtr = new Base();
Base* basePtrToDerived = new Derived();
Derived* derivedPtrToDerived = new Derived();
// Do stuff here
delete basePtr;
delete basePtrToDerived; // if Base has no virtual destructor, only the destructor of Base is called
delete derivedPtrToDerived; // This will always call the destructor of Derived
```

you need a virtual destructor.